# Is it possible to access the html directly after --prod build

Tags: angular, angular8

I am deploying my angular app with `--prod` flag. after the build i see that, there is a folder in the dist folder.

where i can see the all css and html files. after deploying this folder to server, i can able to access the html file from server like:

`http://xzy/app/component/home.html` - I am getting this complaint from client.

How can i deploy my app without accessible the html, images from server directly after the deployment?

Even i see there is `spec` files too..

Comment: no the build command build the project to one html file javascript files , css file you just need to pust this file to the server , it 's look like you pust the hole project include the source file 

Comment: But how can i find the html and javasccript with css file alone? my build output look like my editor folder structure

Comment: this how build file look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZljI.png

Comment: But my build is not look like, it has all folder including asset folder

Comment: the asset folder will be compy include all the files in it but other file no , what verion of angule cli re you using ?

Comment: ng build clears out the contents of /dist

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete the `dist folder.
2. Then run a new build.

It should only produce the following files:

- assets folder with static assets you have in the project files as well
- bunch of '.js' files, which serves as the chunks of the application, like for instance main-esx-xxxxxxxxxx.js, or polyfills-xxxxxx.js etc.
- .css file(s)
- index.html
- 3rdpartylicences.txt
- favicon.ico, and maybe some other static files

Anything esle that resembles the project means you have some misplaced files.The **assets** folder will get copied into the build as-is, and there might be some misconfigurations in your package.json or tsconfig files which can affect how your production build looks like.

Comment: Both file, I have shared here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7ltew can you please help me to figurout the issue?

Comment: Your files look ok. So what happens if you delete the dist folder, and run 'npm run build'? It will produce the dist folder with the application copied inside of it with the current timestamp, do I get that right?

Comment: yes, that's what happening. at present I deleted a line 'src' from assets array in `angular.json`  it works ok.